# Dummy Android app to test permissions

Tags: android, privacy

I basically need an open source/premade app able to show all data obtainable via Android permissions.

It's probably an Android app easy to do by an experienced user in 5 min.

The goal is the following, I want to block selectively this app with tools like XPrivacy, LBE Security and so on and see which data the app can read. Which fake data is feeded to it and so on.

A bonus could be to export the array of all the data via JSON in a text file or something similiar.

Something like in this pic for iOS but a more advanced viewer, no need of a fancy graphic … even just a whole browsable array/object print could work ;)

[image: Screenshot of iOS, showing the values for 'Bluetooh', 'IMEI', 'ICCID' etc.]

Comment: I don't know of such an app for *all* permissions, but for selected ones a few are linked with my [permission list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms) for e.g. `READ_CONTACTS`, `READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS` and `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

Comment: I'm tempted to go on github and start developing one app like that by myself but I fear it could be too much time consuming and discover someone else already did the job for me :\

Comment: Watson combining: "easy to do by an experienced user in 5 min" / "too much time consuming" = ??? :) IMHO even an experienced user had to invest more than 5 min into that. Nevertheless, I like the idea. And be it to shock users into what apps can see :) The apps I've mentioned above are gone from Playstore a while ago already, so it's time for replacements. I'd favor it to be available at F-Droid. And if such an app exists, I'd make sure to link it from my site :)

Comment: Well hmm true is i'm not even the best developer out of there and I wonder wich api level select for the starters... should i go for android 5.1.1 and upper ?

Comment: That's better suited for SO. But I'd make sure it is usable on KK at least, or you might leave out 50%+ of all users :)

Comment: @Izzy I guess we can move to chat and discuss the thing there but i have no idea how to trigger it unless spamming more many comments and having the system give you the option :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33791/discussion-between-user3450548-and-izzy).